# HTML Canvas Drawing

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a red incorrect mark but I have no Idea where to start can anyone help me create one.

I have the following jsfiddle to draw a correct checkmark

https://jsfiddle.net/avmxfz2d/

```
      function drawCorrect(key) {
      var start = 100;
      var mid = 145;
      var end = 250;
      var width = 20;
      var leftX = start;
      var leftY = start;
      var rightX = mid - (width / 2.7);
      var rightY = mid + (width / 2.7);
      var animationSpeed = 5;

      var ctx = document.getElementById(key).getContext('2d');
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';
      var i;
      for (i = start; i < mid; i++) {
        var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(start, start);
          ctx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
          ctx.stroke();
          leftX++;
          leftY++;
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
      }

      for (i = mid; i < end; i++) {
        var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(leftX, leftY);
          ctx.lineTo(rightX, rightY);
          ctx.stroke();
          rightX++;
          rightY--;
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
      }
    }

    drawCorrect('canvas');
```

Here is what I have tried so far https://jsfiddle.net/zj6L8y17/

```
        function drawIncorrect(key) {

      var width = 20;
      var animationSpeed = 5;

      var ctx = document.getElementById(key).getContext('2d');
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

      var startx = 50;
      var starty = 50;
      var endx = 150;
      var endy = 150;
      var curx = startx;
      var cury = starty;

      //Draw left to right
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 50; i < 150; i++) {
        var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.moveTo(startx, starty);
          ctx.lineTo(curx++, cury++);
          ctx.stroke();
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
      }
      ctx.closePath();

      startx = 150;
      starty = 50;
      endx = 50;
      endy = 150
      curx = startx;
      cury = starty;
      //Draw right to left
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 50; i < 150; i++) {
        var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.moveTo(startx, starty);
          ctx.lineTo(curx--, cury++);
          ctx.stroke();
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawIncorrect('canvas');
```

Each leg drawn seperately it works, but if I combine the two animations it just fails

Comment: You've already succeeded in drawing a checkmark with 2 incremental diagonal lines. Make an X by simply by repositioning the 2 diagonal lines -- maybe change the `strokeStyle='red'`.

Comment: I tried, but take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/zj6L8y17/ if I draw each leg seperately it works, but as soon as I combine the two then it draws a straight line

Comment: haha ok think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working

```
    function drawIncorrect(key) {

      var width = 20;
      var animationSpeed = 5;

      var ctx = document.getElementById(key).getContext('2d');
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';


      var lx = 50;
      var ly = 50;

      //Draw left to right
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 50; i < 150; i++) {
        var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
          ctx.lineTo(lx++, ly++);
          ctx.stroke();
          if (ly == 150) {
            var rx = 150;
            var ry = 50;
            ctx.beginPath();
            for (var i = 50; i < 150; i++) {
              var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function() {
                ctx.moveTo(150, 50);
                ctx.lineTo(rx--, ry++);
                ctx.stroke();
              }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
          }
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
      }


    }

    drawIncorrect('canvas');
```